# Emacs: setting doc-view-continuous doesn't work with modified key-bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, docview

I work in **Emacs** with **ergoemacs** minor mode turned on. This minor mode changes *C-n* and *C-p* to *M-k* and *M-i* correspondingly.

In **doc-view** mode I can move up and down inside one page with *M-i* and *M-k* but when the end (beginning) of the page is reached the scrolling stops.

I have set **doc-view-continuous** variable to **t**. Here is the result:

- continuous scrolling with *M-k* and *M-i* doesn't work if **ergoemacs** minor mode is turned on
- continuous scrolling with *C-n* and *C-p* works if **ergoemacs** minor mode is turned off
- next page *C-x,]* and previous page *C-x,[* always work
- continuous scrolling with mouse wheel always works

PS:
While writing this post I've found out the following:

- in **doc-view** mode *C-p* is bound to **doc-view-previous-line-or-previous-page** function which behaves in different ways depending on **doc-view-continuous**
- in **doc-view** mode + **ergoemacs** minor mode *M-i* is bound to **image-previous-line** function

This difference is the reason of the problem. I will try to use **doc-view-mode-hook**.

Edited:
Here is the startup code that works for **ergoemacs** mode:

```lisp
;; adjust docview mode
(setq doc-view-continuous t)
(defun adjust-doc-view ()
  (ergoemacs-local-set-key (kbd "M-i")
    'doc-view-previous-line-or-previous-page)
  (ergoemacs-local-set-key (kbd "M-k")
    'doc-view-next-line-or-next-page)
)
(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'adjust-doc-view)
```

The thing I don't understand is why **doc-view** functions are bound to standard keys but are not bound to **ergoemacs** keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently doc view binds its commands explicitly to `C-n` and `C-p`.  My guess would be that ergoemacs remaps the usual commands that are bound to those keys, to the keys `M-k` and `M-i` instead.  Ergoemacs probably does not know about the doc-view commands in question.

Consider filing an enhancement request for ergoemacs, so that it provides a user option whose value is the list of commands to remap this way.  That way, instead of doing what you do above, you can just customize the option.

For an example of code that defines such an option, you can refer Xah Lee (author of ergoemacs) to file [`icicles-opt.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-opt.el), option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`.